# webcrawling- What are some possible ways to detect a page is loaded using javascript?

Tags: web-crawler

I want to crawl some websites. I'm using selenium/PhantomJS to crawl JS(react, angular, jquery ect.) and python to crawl everything else.

My main issue is that I have no way to distinguish whether a page is loaded using JS or not.

Any ideas would be welcome!

Answer (score 0):

The idea of a page being "loaded" or "done" is a fuzzy one. **Generally speaking, there's no way of knowing.** Web applications are complicated and can change in just about any way at any time.

But unless you're trying to build a generic site indexer, a la Google, **that's probably not an issue you need to solve.** Instead, you're likely aware of *why* you're on a particular page and thus what you expect to *be* there. You should be able to do what a real user does: wait for some piece of meaningful data to appear on the screen, e.g., a page title or some body text:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

driver.get("http://www.example.com")

wait.until(
    EC.text_to_be_present_in_element(
        (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "p"),
        "to be used for illustrative examples"))

link = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("More information")
link.click()

wait.until(
    EC.text_to_be_present_in_element(
        (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h1"),
        "IANA-managed Reserved Domains"))
```

[capybara-py](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/capybara-py) actually makes this kind of synchronization extremely easy and transparent:

```py
import capybara
from capybara.dsl import page

capybara.current_driver = "selenium"

page.visit("http://www.example.com")
page.assert_text("to be used for illustrative examples")
page.click_link("More information")
page.assert_text("IANA-managed Reserved Domains")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So do you think a good work around would be to have a lookup table where each base url is classified after the first request as JS or Not. Using both crawlers to check. And then future instances of that base url will be proccessed appropriately?

Comment: No, I'm saying that, absent some specific examples, I'm not convinced you need to worry about it.

Comment: I'm crawling for educational material on a generic level. I'm currently crawling a decent amaount of pages and up till now I vetted each page before I put it into a 'crawler process' that extracts the revelent information. However, this is quite time intensive and the number of pages i'm crawling is rapidly increasing as I get more material on more subjects. I want to being to automate the process.

Comment: What do you mean by "a generic level"? What are these sites? What is this educational material? How do you decide which sites to crawl? Which pages to visit? What material to "extract"?

Comment: Say I'm looking for material on Binomial Distributions. The sites could be any with that information, khan academy, mit ocw, bbc bitesize, youtube ect. The material could be anything, pdf, video, article. I then extract the title and contentent producer (usually the site name, univeristy name or video creator) , make a note of them and put them in a database for later use.

Comment: And it's that initial search you're scripting? Or the "latest use"? (Or both?)

Comment: Yes the initial search, but I have a pool of urls that come up most often. So I'm planning on starting there or creating a script that queries google and then puts the top 50 or so results in a queue and crawls those.

Comment: I'm not convinced you'll even need or want to worry about this.

Since you're planning to seed your crawling with Google, consider the results they'll give you: if someone wants their content to be indexable (and thus crawlable) by a search engine, they're generally going to make sure it returns a server-side rendered version. That means you probably don't need to run JavaScript.

But regardless, I'm not sure you're going to be able to get around needing to know specifics about particular domains. Searching for specific, structured data with unstructured input would be hugely complicated.